# Почему не отображается polygon

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

Почему данный `polygon` не отображается?

```html
<svg>
  <polygon points="569.2050807568878,518 396,618 222.7949192431123,518.0000000000001 222.79491924311225,318.00000000000006 395.99999999999994,218 569.2050807568878,318.00000000000006" fill="none" stroke="orange" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Размеры свг укажите, фигуру просто не видно из за координат

Comment: Напишите для начала viewBox 0 0 1000 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот конечный результат, в котором нет лишних пустых полей, шестиугольник расположен по центру SVG и код оптимизирован (один знак после запятой вместо 14-ти)

Красная рамка это границы холста SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="346.4" height="400" viewBox="222.8 218 346.4 400" style="border:1px solid crimson">
  <polygon id="poly" points="569.2 518 396 618 222.8 518 222.8 318 396 218 569.2 318" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
<script>
console.log(poly.getBBox())
</script>
```

Как это сделано:

Полигону присвоен `id="poly"` и с помощью метода JS `getBBox()` выводятся минимально, достаточные координаты, ширина и высота прямоугольника описывающего полигон.

Эти данные подставляются во `viewBox="222.8 218 346.4 400"` `width="x"`, `hieght="y"`